# How to ignore errors from WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder?

Tags: azure-identity

We are using azure-identity java library and the below code to get TokenCredential which is in turn used to access azure resources.

```
public TokenCredential buildCredential() {
    return new ChainedTokenCredentialBuilder()
        .addFirst(new WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder().build())
        .addLast(new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build())
        .build();
}
```

When we are trying to debug locally we are getting below exception and it stops processing.

IllegalArgumentException: Must provide non-null values for Client ID, Tenant ID, Service Token File Path properties in WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder

We have found below solution. Is it possible to implement it using the earlier code without depending on active profiles? Our expectation is that it should continue processing without throwing any exception and use AzureCliCredentialBuilder.

```
public TokenCredential buildCredential() {
    if (activeProfiles != null && activeProfiles.contains("local")) {
        return new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
    }

    return new WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IllegalArgumentException` error occurred due to missing required parameters for `WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder`.

If you want to ignore errors from `WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder`, you can catch the `CredentialUnavailableException` that it throws and continue with the next credential in the chain, which is `AzureCliCredentialBuilder` in your case.

Here's an updated version of your `buildCredential` method that implements this approach:

```
public TokenCredential buildCredential() {
    try {
        return new ChainedTokenCredentialBuilder()
            .addFirst(new WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder().build())
            .addLast(new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build())
            .build();
    } catch (CredentialUnavailableException e) {
        // WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder is not available, ignore and try AzureCliCredentialBuilder
        return new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

This will try to get a token from `WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder` first, and if it's not available, it will catch the `CredentialUnavailableException` and try to get a token from `AzureCliCredentialBuilder`

**Reference:**

[Troubleshoot Azure-hosted application authentication - Azure SDK for Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/troubleshooting-authentication-azure-hosted#troubleshoot-workloadidentitycredential)

Comment: Thank you @Venkatesan. We have already fixed our code as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public TokenCredential buildCredential() {
    if (activeProfiles != null && activeProfiles.contains("local")) {
        return new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
    }

    return new WorkloadIdentityCredentialBuilder().build();
}
```